# How to create IF functions inside logicalTest parameter for IF function in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

I was told it may be possible to nest IF functions inside the IF function in Microsoft Graph but I cannot figure out the syntax.

I want to recreate a function like this
`=IF(A1="", B1, (B1*C1*D1))`

So in Microsoft Graph, instead of a simple body for the IF statement being

```
{ 
  "logicalTest": true, 
  "valueIfTrue": 20, 
  "valueIfFalse": 10 
}
```

it could be something like

```
{ 
  "logicalTest": "1=1", 
  "valueIfTrue": 20, 
  "valueIfFalse": 10 
}
```

but I can't figure out the correct syntax to make it work.

This is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.functions?view=excel-js-preview&preserve-view=true#excel-excel-functions-if-member(1)) for the if function, and according to the doc, it may be possible. But I posted a similar question last month and user [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667292/microsoft-graph-how-to-make-a-more-complicated-if-function-maybe-nest-function) it should be possible but can't figure out the syntax.

Any ideas? Thank you!

I've tried experimenting with different syntaxes but no luck; =true "=true" '=true' =1=1 "=1=1".

Comment: It seems to me that only true or false value is allowed for logicalTest

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation for this, but based on my testing:

- `logicalTest` property accepts only `true`/`false` value
- `valueIfTrue`, `valueIfFalse` properties accept boolean, number or string

```
{ 
  "logicalTest": true, 
  "valueIfTrue": 20, // "Yes", true
  "valueIfFalse": 10 
}
```

What's not working for `if` function even if it works for other functions is a json that represents a reference to an excel cell with true/false value

```
{ 
  "logicalTest": {
    "address": "Sheet1!A1"
  }, 
  "valueIfTrue": 20,
  "valueIfFalse": 10 
}
```

or string with expression to be evaluated

```
{ 
  "logicalTest": "=TRUE()", 
  "valueIfTrue": 20,
  "valueIfFalse": 10 
}
```

In both cases, the endpoint returns error response.

Comment: Thank you for testing! I was thinking the same but was hopeful with the "logicalTest" has the ability to take Excel.FunctionResult<any> as an input. But don't believe putting a nested if statement was their purpose here. Thanks again!